# Advantages of different ways to open windows

Tags: javascript, performance, titanium-mobile, appcelerator

So I was reading this question here: [How to load another js file on a button click in titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849977/how-to-load-another-js-file-on-a-button-click-in-titanium)

And there are two different ways to open windows in titanium. I was wondering if there are any major performance differences or advantages of each way of opening the window? I have been looking at the documentation here:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window

Also I am not using Alloy.

Anyone know if there are any advantages of using each of the methods? Code snippets below.

**Method 1**

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : 'white',
    url             : 'home.js' //Path to your js file
});
win.open();
```

home.js

```
var myWin = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
//You can add your controls here and do your stuff.
// Note that never try to open myWin in this page since you've already opened this window
```

**Method 2**

```
//In your current page
loginbutton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var Home = require('/ui/common/Home');
    var homePage = new Home();
    homePage.open();
});
```

Home.js

```
function Home() {
    var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        layout : 'vertical',
        backgroundColor:'white'
    });
    //Do your stuff here
    //Add other controls here

    return self;
}
module.exports = Home;
```

Comment: opening new windows using method 2 is recommended now, since it uses commonJS method. i.e. You are creating each window as modules and it's a type of pattern. More over, Appcelerator also promoting commonJS module more since they are planning to remove the `Ti.include()` method from the future releases. So better to use the 2nd method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1 is defunct. Don't use it. Only use Method2 which is the CommonJS way.

Please see the CommonJS best practises documentation:

[CommonJS Modules in Titanium](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/CommonJS+Modules+in+Titanium)