# How can I create a home button?

Tags: button, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am pretty new in the programming world. I am using Titanium, and I want a button that when I clicked on it, it will go back to the home window. Obviously, the button will be in another window.

I tried `win2.open()` and `win2.show()`, but it is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: what is `win2`? Can you show us more codes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use titanium navigational controller

https://github.com/vuinguyen/Ti-Navigation-Controller

it would give you button for previous and home window

Answer (score 0):

Jacl,

If you are in second window, just close that window on the click event of your button in the second window.
Try the following in second window

```
//I'm assuming that you have came from window1 to window2
//and you have a button btnHome at window 2 used to navigate back to home page

var thisWindow = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
btnHome.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    thisWindow.close(); //Will close the current window and display the previous one
});
```

There is a similar question which is used to navigate between windows. Go through [Titanium Mobile: cant navigate between pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949025/titanium-mobile-cant-navigate-between-pages/14949895#14949895).

You can use the following links also for references

1. http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-url
2. http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Global-method-require

Comment: But thanks for answering . Maybe it is a context issue Do you think?